# Wicket page destroy event

Tags: java, apache, servlets, wicket

I have a regular wicket page and I need to catch and event when we navigate away from that page OR the page is destroyed either would work.

I have tried to override all sensable sounding methods none of them were triggered.

Is there an easy way to do this? Registering the page to some listener would work just as well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by destroyed? After a request the page is served to the user and then cached and serialized. What do you want to do with the page?

Comment: Destroy might be a stupid term I'll admit. Let's say I want to catch an event when we navigate away from the page, or we open any other page.

The point is I need to run some server side code once we navigate away from the page. I welcome any solution.

Comment: This is a tricky one, there is some discussion about it [here](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Get-return-value-of-ajax-event-in-Wicket-6-9-1-td4662300.html) Maybe it can help you

Comment: I believe there are simply too many caveats in trying to detect when the user tries to navigate away. For example, user opening a link in a new page or user losing connection, among others. I strongly recommend trying to find an alternate solution to listening to user navigating away, if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured I'll post the solution here so we have one on SO as well.

```
private class ProcessAfterCloseBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {
        @Override
        public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
            super.renderHead(component, response);
            response.render(new OnDomReadyHeaderItem("window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {"
                    + getCallbackScript() + "};"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
            attributes.setAsynchronous(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            //Do whatever you need to do.
        }
}
```